# Is it possible to manually sort Firebase autogenerated keys?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

In order to work with already available data within the app, I want to reuse a Snapshot result from a custom Query.
This custom Query searches by value `q.orderByChild(child)`.

The idea is that both, the custom query, and the normal query (by normal I mean one that brings the children in the order they were pushed) work with similar limits.

The limit is 15 children, which is a small number, and part of the reason I believe this to be the most economically sounding approach.

...
**When the database reaches a certain amount of children (> 15), the normal query becomes unused, and other queries become available.**

This makes this normal query wasteful, and If I could reuse available data from other Queries, like the one with the custom Query, would be great.

[image: firebase's real time pushed keys]

At first glance it seems the database is generating keys in alphabetical order, in which case I could use a `Collections.sort(list, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);` to replicate a normal query order.

What I am not sure is if the pushed keys follow some other rules that I am not aware of, like what about lower case and upper case?
OR How would the algorithm behave with minus signs and other non alphabetical characters.

In short is it possible to manually sort Firebase autogenerated keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function seems to be working as intended.
The Comparable interface of String.class seems to be handling everything without any inconvenience, and the autogenerated Firebase keys seem to be created in accordance to the Comparator's sorting guideline

```
public enum OrderType {
    DESC, ASC
}

public static<X, Y extends Comparable<? super Y>> List<X> query(
        List<X> from,
        Function<X, Y> orderBy,
        OrderType orderType
) {
    List<X> result = new ArrayList<>(from);
    Comparator<Y> comparator = orderType.equals(OrderType.ASC) ?
            (o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2) :
            (o1, o2) -> o2.compareTo(o1);
    return result
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(
                    orderBy,
                    comparator
            ))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here the implementation:

```
private LiveData<List<Element>> testPickUpElements() {
        return Transformations.map(
                baseValueElements,
                input -> {
                    return Comparators.query(
                            input,
                            Element::getElementDBKey,
                            OrderType.ASC
                    );
                }
        );
    }
```